# Changing the background color in a search bar

Tags: css, algolia

I'm about to start using Algolia Instant Search on my website, but I can't figure out what CSS elements to set in order to change the background color the way I would with text. I know it's possible because other websites have dark search bars and use them, but putting background-color="black" in the DIV doesn't work.

Their documentation doesn't say anything about colors for the search bar, and googling it hasn't come up with anything either. https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/js/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you read through [this part](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/js/#widget-param-cssclasses)?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I have no idea how to apply that to the background color, which is why I'm asking a question here. I'm sure if I was proficient in CSS I could figure it out. It's probably something like input: background-color="black" but I really have no idea how to make that API bit work with the kind of CSS I can google.

Comment: `background-color="black" in the DIV` inline styles are the root of all evil ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
  // ...
  cssClasses: {
    input: 'bg-black',
  },
});
```

And then in your CSS file:

```css
.bg-black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

You're essentially asking InstantSearch to add an additional class called `bg-black` to the HTML input element it renders. Then in your CSS, you're targeting that CSS selector and adding styles to it.

More docs here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/js/#widget-param-cssclasses